# Printing content with Bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I have a feature in my application to print html page with Bluetooth printer. We use this  [model](http://www.zonerich.com/english/ab-320m.htm). I know that since Android 4.4 KitKat it know [supports](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) printing with WiFi printer. But I need to support printing on older versions of Android and for Bluetooth printer. After some research I found that Android does not support printing with Bluetooth printers because Android does not support Basic Printing Profile as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656199/bluetooth-and-wifi-printing-for-android) or [here].[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229732/bluetooth-printing-on-android) But nevertheless I've found that people somehow [print content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145787/bluetooth-printer-issue-in-android). So I'm interested are there some common ways or may be there is a standard API for this? Because I think it is a widespread feature and it is strange if Android doesn't support it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Print from your Android application with Bluetooth Printer

[Print from your Android application with Bluetooth Printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23557722/print-from-your-android-application-with-bluetooth-printer?lq=1)

i got the answer here

Comment: The link should be posted as a comment under the question, indicating that the question is a duplicate.  Adding an answer that is just a link to another answer is frowned upon.

Comment: @MarkLeiber no you can see through this link there is a "Click here" in  2 answer that git project will help you it worked!!!

Comment: I'm not disagreeing that there is an answer at the link you posted.  I'm trying to tell you that posting a link to another Stack Overflow answer should be done as a comment.  Answers like the one you provided are often down-voted because they don't add anything new.  As a new user, I hope you'll take my advice.  Good luck.